# Geogaphy to Geometry EFCore migration - The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography on STDistance conversion

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

We are migrating our EF6 code to EF Core and have migrated all the code to use Geometry instead of Geography, though the DB columns are still in the Geography format, but from what I understand that should not be a problem.

The issue we have is with a specific query (simplified here):

```
Geomtery geo = new Point( searchCriteria.Address.Lng, searchCriteria.Address.Lat );
var query = this.context.Adverts.Where( x => x.Address.GeoLocation.IsWithinDistance( geo, searchCriteria.Radius ) );
var list = query.ToList();
```

Which converts into the following sql:

```
DECLARE @__8__locals1_geo_0 geography = 0x00000000010CF1BDBF417BF5F8BF60F545179BC04A40;
DECLARE @__radius_1 float = 80467.199999999997E0;

SELECT ...
FROM [Adverts] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Addresses] AS [a0] ON [a].[Address_AddressID] = [a0].[AddressID]
WHERE [a0].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@__8__locals1_geo_0) <= @__radius_1
```

which throws the error:

*The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 ("@__8__locals1_geo_0"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider*

I have tried to run this `Where` statement after the `ToList()` call, which does work as all the data is then in memory, but we need this to work as it used to with EF6 - in the query - so we are not returning unnecessary data from the DB.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you specify the correct SRID for `geo`?

Comment: urgh, Yes! I wasn't aware that the SRID was a requirement. It now works, thank you. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.